# Print active sheet as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to formulate VBA code on a MAC to print the active sheet to PDF.

I have downloaded examples from this and other sites. All of them produce the same result:

> Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

I have code to print the active sheet without any filename or path settings.

```
Sub PrintToPDF()

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:xlTypePDF, Filename:="XXX.pdf", _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have frequently come across this problem and found a work-around to deal with it.
I have found that if I quit Excel and then open it and load the workbook the macro runs quite happily.   It seems that some previous Excel activity leaves some garbage which causes the problem.   By quitting Excel this garbage is removed or reset.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It should work.

```
Sub PrintToPDF()

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
FileName:="XXX.pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```